# Prove $R(a \times b) = Ra \times Rb$ given $R \in \mathcal{SO}(3)$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification, rotations

Here, $R$ is a proper rotation matrix, and $(\times)$ is the cross-product.

I already found 3 ways of proving this, all have problems, and I am requesting an elegant approach.

(1) Direct calculation, $R = R_{\mathbf{u},\theta}$ has an explicit expression, where $\mathbf{u}$ is the vector about which the rotation of $\theta$ is carried out. It is essentially possible to calculate both sides and compare. Inelegant.

(2) Using antisymmetric matrices: $Ra \times Rb=S(Ra)Rb=RS(a)R^\top Rb=RS(a)b=R(a\times b)$.

 My issue with this is that the equality I am trying to prove, is used to prove $RS(a)R^\top=S(Ra)$. And so using this feels circular.

(3) $Ra \times Rb=\|Ra\|\|Rb\|\sin(Ra,Rb)\mathbb{\hat{u}_1}$ and $a \times b=\|a\|\|b\|\sin(a,b)\mathbb{\hat{u}_2}$.

Here, essentially $\|Ra\|$ should equal $\|a\|$ since $R$ only affects orientation.

Because the relative orientation does not change, the $\sin(\cdot)$ term should be equal.

Likewise, $\mathbb{\hat{u}_1}$ and $\mathbb{\hat{u}_2}$ intuitively I know are equal but I am having a hard time expressing it.

Lastly, I have no idea how to bridge $(a \times b)$ to $R(a \times b)$.

I intuitively see it, and perhaps $\det R = 1$ might be useful, but I feel it is hard to write.

Please, a fourth approach is welcome, and insight is always appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the cross product $a\times b$ is characterized by the property that

$$
\det(x,a,b)=\langle x,a\times b\rangle, \qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^3.
$$

Now let $R\in\mathcal{SO}(3)$. Then by using the fact that $R^{\mathsf{T}} = R^{-1}$, we get

$$
\langle x, R(a \times b) \rangle
= \langle R^{\mathsf{T}}x, a \times b \rangle
= \langle R^{-1}x, a \times b \rangle
= \det(R^{-1}x, a, b).
$$

Then, utilizing the assumption $\det(R) = 1$,

$$
= \det(R) \det(R^{-1}x, a, b)
= \det(x, Ra, Rb)
= \langle x, Ra \times Rb \rangle.
$$

Finally, since $\langle x, R(a \times b) \rangle = \langle x, Ra \times Rb \rangle$ holds for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$, the desired identity follows.

---

**Addendum.** A similar argument shows that, for any invertible $3\times 3$ real matrix $T$,

$$ T(a \times b) = \frac{1}{\det T}(T T^{\mathsf{T}})( Ta \times Tb). $$

Comment: Very interesting addendum, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach I see is the following,
$$\langle R(a\times b), Ra\rangle = (Ra)^TR(a\times b)$$
$$=a^T(a\times b)=\langle a\times b, a\rangle =0$$
Similarly, 
$$\langle R(a\times b), Rb\rangle = 0$$
Hence, it follows that 
$$R(a\times b)= k( Ra\times Rb)$$
for some non-zero real number $k$. Now, observe that,
$$\frac{1}{k}||R(a\times b)||^2$$
$$\langle R(a\times b), Ra\times Rb \rangle = det (R(a\times b), Ra,Rb)$$
$$=(det R)(det(a\times b,a,b))$$
$$=||a\times b||^2$$
$$=||R(a\times b)||^2$$
Required result follows.

Comment: In the first step you prove that $Ra\times rb$ is orthogonal to $R(a\times b)$. That proves that $R(a\times b)$ and $Ra\times Rb$ are linearly dependent. I don't see how that already implies that they also have the same length.

Comment: @celtschk, yeah, additional argument is required. Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this is really different from what you had in mind, but I would explain this as follows. It has a bit of Lie algebra air to it.

Let $R_{\vec{a},t}$ be the right-handed rotation about the axis $\vec{a}$ by the angle $t|\vec{a}|$. These form a 1-parameter group under composition, basically just add the angles of rotation as the axis is constant. The Lie algebra trick is to study the derivatives of such 1-parameter groups at $t=0$. The reason why cross products often appear when studying rotations in $\Bbb{R}^3$ is the following.

> For all vectors $\vec{b}\in\Bbb{R}^3$ we have
>   $$\frac d{dt}R_{\vec{a},t}\vec{b}\big\vert_{t=0}=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}.$$ In other words, cross product by $\vec{a}$ is an infinitesimal generator for the group of rotations about the axis $\vec{a}$.

The other fact I would use is the observation that

> For all rotations $R$ we have the conjugation relation
>   $$ R\circ R_{\vec{a},t}\circ R^{-1}=R_{R\vec{a},t}.$$ 
>   In other words, to rotate a vector $\vec{b}$ about the vector $R\vec{a}$ we can first apply $R^{-1}$, *to move the scene to be about rotations about $\vec{a}$*, then rotate about $\vec{a}$ by the prescribed angle, and then as the last step rotate the axis back to $R\vec{a}$.

We have the obvious identity
$$
(R\circ R_{\vec{a},t}\circ R^{-1})R\vec{b}=R(R_{\vec{a},t}\vec{b}).\qquad(*)
$$
And your claim follows from equating the derivatives of both sides of $(*)$ at $t=0$.

---

Don't know whether this was buried in one of your proofs, or whether you see too much handwavium in it.

Comment: I deleted a latter section. While it explained the first boxed fact when $\vec{a}$ is one of the standard basis vectors, I think that my claim of the first boxed fact following from that by the second leads to a circular argument.

Comment: I did not think of it from this perspective. It's new to me. Thank you so much for broadening the horizons, I will enjoy digging into this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a component-wise proof. Note that I'm using the Einstein convention: If an index appears twice in a product, it is summed over. For example
$$(Rv)_i = R_{ij}v_j$$
actually means
$$(Rv)_i = \sum_{j=1}^3 R_{ij} v_j$$
because $j$ appears twice in $R_{ij}v_j$.

Also in case you don't know those symbols,
$$\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & i=j\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
and
$$\epsilon_{ijk} = \begin{cases}
  1 & ijk \in \{123,231,312\}\\
 -1 & ijk \in \{132,213,321\}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$
Then we can easily check that
$$(a\times b)_i = \epsilon_{ijk}a_j b_k.$$
The equation we want to prove is
$$R(a\times b)=Ra\times Rb.$$
Now since $R$ is invertible, we can multiply both sides with $R^{-1}$ and get an equivalent equation:
$$a\times b=R^{-1}(Ra\times R_b)$$
Thus we get:
\begin{aligned}
&&(a\times b)_i &= (R^{-1}(Ra\times Rb))_i\\
\iff&&(a\times b)_i &= (R^{-1})_{ij}(Ra\times Rb)_j\\
\iff&&(a\times b)_i &= R_{ji}(Ra\times Rb)_j && \text{orthogonality of $R$}\\
\iff&&\epsilon_{ikl}a_kb_l &= R_{ji} \epsilon_{jmn}(Ra)_m(Rb)_n\\
\iff&&\epsilon_{ikl}a_kb_l &= R_{ji} \epsilon_{jmn}R_{mk}a_kR_{nl}b_l\\
\iff&&\epsilon_{ikl}a_kb_l &= (\epsilon_{jnm} R_{ji} R_{mk} R_{nl}) a_k b_l
\end{aligned}
Thus we have to prove that
$$\epsilon_{ikl} = \epsilon_{jnm} R_{ji} R_{mk} R_{nl} \tag{*}$$
Now $\epsilon$ is completely characterized by the following two properties:

- $\epsilon_{123} = 1$
- Exchange of two indices changes the sign.

So let's check both properties for the right hand side of the above equation (note that the free indices are $i$, $k$, and $l$):

- $ \epsilon_{jmn} R_{j1} R_{m2} R_{n3} \stackrel?= 1$

  The left hand side is the determinant of $R$, which by assumption is $1$, so this
  equation is indeed true.
- Exchange of two indices: Let's without loss of generality exchange the last two indices, $§k$ and $l$.

  Clearly due to the commutativity of multiplication, we have
  $$\epsilon_{jnm} R_{ji} R_{ml} R_{nk} = \epsilon_{jnm} R_{ji} R_{nk} R_{ml}$$
  Now the indices of $\epsilon$ in this term are summed over, therefore we can just
  rename them without changing anything. In particular, we exchange the names $m$
  and $n$:
  $$\epsilon_{jnm} R_{ji} R_{nk} R_{ml} = \epsilon_{jnm} R_{ji} R_{mk} R_{nl}$$
  Now we exchange the last two indices of the $\epsilon$ factor:
  $$\epsilon_{jnm} = -\epsilon_{jmn}$$
  Putting all together, we then get
  $$\epsilon_{jnm} R_{ji} R_{ml} R_{nk} = -\epsilon_{jmn} R_{ji} R_{mk} R_{nl}$$
  Thus exchanging $k$ and $l$ indeed changes the sign.

Thus we see that equation $(*)$ indeed holds, and thus $R(a\times b)=Ra\times Rb$.